# Asp.Net Request Validation error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, validation, request

I have allowed one of the text box in my web form to allow HTML tags to be submitted to server. Now All HTML tags are working except the meta tag. Is something i need to configure in IIS side?

At first i thought it might be related to SSL since code is working as expected on DEV machine but not on server where the same code has been deployed.

Comment: you need to provide sample code

Comment: One of the text-box contains encoded html "&lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Language&quot; content=&quot;en-us&quot;&gt;" and even other HTML tags. But once i remove the above text it starts working. Problem is not about the HTMl tags its specific to the meta tag only.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with our request filtering. When i checked before recahing the request to Web Server it was getting blocked by our filtering framework where meta tag was not allowed.

Comment: Please consider to accept your own answer, so others can see that a solution for the problem was found :-)